# What is the root cause of distributed.scheduler.KilledWorker exception?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to run a Dask job on a YARN cluster. This jobs reads and writes to HDFS using the [hdfs3 library](https://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

- When I run it on a cluster **without** a Kerberos security layer, it runs fine.
- But, on a cluster **with** a Kerberos security layer, I had to implement the solution [here](https://github.com/dask/hdfs3/issues/91) to avoid Kerberos related errors. Running the same job, led to the following error:

```
  File "/fsstreamdevl/f6_development/acoustics/acoustics_analysis_dask/acoustics_analytics/task_runner/task_runner.py", line 123, in run
    dask.compute(tasks)
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 446, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2568, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1822, in gather
    asynchronous=asynchronous,
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 753, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 331, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 316, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1653, in _gather
    six.reraise(type(exception), exception, traceback)
  File "/anaconda_env/projects/f6acoustics/dev/dask_yarn_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
distributed.scheduler.KilledWorker: ('__call__-6af7aa29-2a09-45f3-a5e2-207c06562672', <Worker 'tcp://10.194.211.132:11927', memory: 0, processing: 1>)
```

- Strangely enough, running the same solution on the former cluster **without** a Kerberos security layer, I get the same error.

Looking at the YARN application logs, I see the following traceback, but cannot tell what it means.

```
distributed.nanny - INFO - Closing Nanny at 'tcp://10.194.211.133:17659'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/05/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_171773/container_e47_1560931326013_171773_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 242, in _feed
    send_bytes(obj)
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/05/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_171773/container_e47_1560931326013_171773_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/05/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_171773/container_e47_1560931326013_171773_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 404, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/05/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_171773/container_e47_1560931326013_171773_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

End of LogType:dask.worker.log
```

I do not see any explicit messages in the logs about low memory. Would anyone know how to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

hdfs3 is not actively maintained any more. You have two main choices for interacting with HDFS:

- pyarrow's [hdfs driver](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#hadoop-file-system-hdfs) (via libhdfs jni library), which requires you to have java and hadoop requirements correctly set up and available to the session calling it
- webhdfs such as in [fsspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.webhdfs.WebHDFS), which does not need java libraries, and can interact with kerberos *if* HTTP authentication is allowed on your system.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant. However, isn't this more `dask.distributed` related than `hdfs3` related?

Comment: I cannot tell from the traceback what killed the worker, but I would hazard a guess at a segfault in the libhdfs3 library. The worker just calls python code, so unless it gets killed by the system (e.g., too much memory), it is unlikely that any normal python exception would do so.

Comment: (NB: hdfs3 is a thin layer over libhdfs3 C++ code, called with ctypes; I think you probably knew that)

Comment: I don't see any errors related to memory in the YARN logs. I instead tried the pyarrow's hdfs driver as you suggested, but it failed with the exact same exception. Would you agree that this is now related to `dask.distributed`?

Comment: Hmmm. Since it depends on whether kerberos is in play, does seem unlikely. You may want to add extra debug output to your function to see at what point it quits (if this is consistent).

Comment: I agree. And may I ask how to get print statements to work inside the functions that are processed in the workers? I added print statements to these functions however I'm not seeing their output in the YARN logs (when I do yarn logs -applicationId {id}).

Comment: Yep, isn't that in the YARN application logs when you run: "yarn logs -applicationId {application_id}"?

Comment: I am not certain, yarn isn't my forte

Comment: Sure, but doesn't Dask have a way of retrieving worker logs?

Comment: It would be conceivable to have some sort of centralised logging, you could suggest it as a feature, but would require some additional plugin on the scheduler and more communication

Comment: (you can proxy printed logs via the scheduler dashboard, under the info tab, if you have routes set up correctly, while the worker lives)